# Ref resets between different calls of my custom hook in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a hook called `useWallet` to manage smart contract interaction:

```
import {ethers, InterfaceAbi, parseEther} from "ethers";
import { useRef } from "react";

const useWallet = () => {
    const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum)
    const signer = useRef<ethers.JsonRpcSigner>();

    const connect = async () => {
        signer.current = await provider.getSigner();
        console.log(signer.current);
    };

    const deployContract = async (abi: InterfaceAbi, bytecode: string) => {
        console.log(signer.current);
        if (!signer.current) {
            throw new Error("Signer not connected");
        }

        const factory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, bytecode, signer.current)
        await factory.deploy(parseEther("0"))
    };

    return {
        connect,
        deployContract,
        signer
    };
}

export default useWallet;
```

On my `Home` page, I call the `connect` method, and everything is OK (Metamask wallet opens):

```
export default function Home() {
    const { connect } = useWallet()

    useEffect(() => {
        connect().catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }, [])

  return <MyChildComponent />
}
```

The problem is when I try to call the `deployContract` function (in `MyChildComponent`) the `signer` is always `undefined`.

It looks like at each `useWallet` call the `signer` is reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because every time you call a hook or a component, you get a completely independent instance. So this `signer.current` will be uniquely tied to each `useWallet` call.

To have a global instance, I would suggest you use the [Context API](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context). As an example like so:

```js
// WalletContextProvider.js

import { createContext, useContext } from "react";

const WalletContext = createContext();

export default function WalletContextProvider({ children }) {
  const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
  const signer = useRef<ethers.JsonRpcSigner>();

  const connect = async () => {
    signer.current = await provider.getSigner();
    console.log(signer.current);
  };

  const deployContract = async (abi: InterfaceAbi, bytecode: string) => {
    console.log(signer.current);
    if (!signer.current) {
      throw new Error("Signer not connected");
    }

    const factory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, bytecode, signer.current);
    await factory.deploy(parseEther("0"));
  };

  return (
    <WalletContext.Provider
      value={{
        connect,
        deployContract,
        signer,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </WalletContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useWalletContext() {
  return useContext(WalletContext);
}
```

Everywhere you need the wallet info, grab them like below. This way you are always referring to the same instance:

```js
import { useWalletContext } from "./WalletContextProvider"; // Make sure you use the correct path.

export default function SomeComponent() {
  const { connect } = useWalletContext();

  // ...
}
```

Finally, ensure, for example, in `index.js`, you render your components wrapped by `WalletContextProvider`:

```js
import WalletContextProvider from "./WalletContextProvider"; // Make sure you use the correct path.

//...

<WalletContextProvider>
  <App/>
</WalletContextProvider>
```